# Laravel Routes returning 404 on localhost

Tags: laravel, routes, nested-routes

Hello in laravel resource i have two views one is admin and users folder i can access both without any problem admin moves me to dashboard and users will access my default. here for accessing  dashboard.

```
Route::get('admin/dash', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
});
```

but in admin folder inside views i created

> secondpage.balde.php

file which contains users info and in web routes i defined this

```
Route::get('userss', 'UsersController@show');
```

from admin dashboard when i goto userManagement or secondpage.blade.php using

```
<a class="p-2 text-white" href="userss">Manage Users</a>
```

artisan command to list routes works perfectly

```
|        | GET|HEAD | userss                 |                  | App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@show                         | web
```

laravel returns 404 | Not found. thanks

Folder Structure

**resources** have two folders **admin and users**.
**admin** has **views** folder inside it
**users** have **views** folder inside it
generally resources**/admin/views** and **/users/views**
**the problem is accessing inside resources/admin/views**

Comment: `href="userss"` vs `href="/userss"` maybe?

Comment: In your `Route::get` use `/userss` instead of `userss`

Comment: And I see a typo in your blade naming. You named your blade as `secondpage.balde.php` but it should be `secondpage.blade.php`

Comment: i tested it interchangeably on /userss and userss but not working

Comment: @aliozgurr That makes no difference `Route::get('/users')` is the same as `Route::get('users')`

Comment: @khal Did you use `/userss` in the _href_ of your _link_ too? If you are at `admin/dash` a link with `href="userss"` will try to open `admin/userss` - which doesn't exist. A link with `href="/userss"` will try to open `/userss` - which _does_ exist

Comment: @kerbh0Iz yes i used /userss

Comment: name your routes. Route::get('userss','UsersController@show')->name('routeName');

Comment: Assuming your server is running on localhost:8000, what do you get if you manually enter `http://localhost:8000/userss` in your adress bar?

Comment: then call it on links href="{{route('routeName')}}"

Comment: @Soroosh i name it but View [userss] not found.

Comment: ok. so can u give us your view folders to see what is going on? where is your userss.blade.php file?

Comment: @Sorooshn updated the question put it in end of it thanks

Comment: Are you sure your `UsersController@show` is not using `Model::find()` or something related? These kind of functions return you a 404 as well if not found.(maybe run the function without code first)

Comment: You care calling `href="userss"` from `127.0.0.1:800/admin/dash` so your browser call the path `admin/dash/userss`, which is giving you a 404 error. So give a slash before the path, so that It can be call from root : `href="/userss"` as @kerbh0lz said already

Answer (score -1):

**first set name for route**

```
Route::get('userss', 'UsersController@show')->name('users');
```

**next can call route function easy**

```
<a class="p-2 text-white" href="{{route('users')}}">Manage Users</a>
```

Comment: `route('userss')` doesn't exist though, you named it `'users'`

Comment: not copy ! It was just a typo (users)

Route::get('userss', 'UsersController@show')->name('users'); 
<a class="p-2 text-white" href="{{route('users')}}">Manage Users</a>